# How to read ssm parameters in a shell script in aws data pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-data-pipeline

I'm setting up a data pipeline in aws. and plan to use a "getting started using ShellCommandActivity" template to run a shell script. how can i pass  credentials stored in ssm parameter as a parameter to this script.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't verified that, but [ShellCommandActivity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-shellcommandactivity.html) is similar to [ShellScriptConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-shellscriptconfig.html) from what I can tell. Based on the examples provided for these commands, I would think that you could pass the ssm param name as follows:

```
{
  "id" : "CreateDirectory",
  "type" : "ShellCommandActivity",
  "command" : "your-script.sh <name-of-your-parameter>"
}
```

or

```
{
  "id" : "CreateDirectory",
  "type" : "ShellCommandActivity",
  "scriptUri" : "s3://my-bucket/example.sh",
  "scriptArgument" : ["<name-of-your-parameter>"]
}
```

and in the `example.sh` you would use `$1` to refer to the value of the argument passed.